# Struct value types in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I understand the difference between 'Value Types' and 'Reference Types'. I know 'Structures' are 'Value Types' and according to the Swift documentation all the values stored by the structure are themselves value types. Now my question is what if I have a stored property in a Struct that is an instance of a class. In that case, would the whole class would be copied or just its address?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It copies the pointer to the instance. I just tested this in a playground.

```
struct MyStruct {
    var instance: MyClass
}

class MyClass {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        println("inited \( self.name )") // Prints "inited Alex" only once
    }
}

var foo = MyClass(name: "Alex") // make just one instance
var a = MyStruct(instance: foo) // make a struct that contains that instance
var b = a                       // copy the struct that references the instance

foo.name = "Wayne"              // Update the instance

// Check to see if instance was updated everywhere.
a.instance.name // Wayne
b.instance.name // Wayne
```

What is different though, is that it's now two different references to the same object. So if you change one struct to a different instance, you are only hanging it for that struct.

```
b.instance = MyClass(name: "Vik")

// a and b no longer reference the same instance
a.instance.name // Wayne
b.instance.name // Vik
```

---

The playground is a great way to test out questions like these. I did not know the answer definitively when I read this question. But now I do :)

So don't be afraid to go play.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misread the documentation. According to the The Swift Programming Language,

> All structures and enumerations are value types in Swift. This means that any structure and enumeration instances you create—**and any value types they have as properties**—are always copied when they are passed around in your code.

Since classes are reference types, not value types, they are not copied even if they are properties of a value type, so only the address is copied.